# Is it possible to attach arbitrary data to an actual file in PHP

Tags: php

This is quite an 'out there' question but i've been thinking about some simplification in my app and if this is at all possible would be a really clean way of doing things.

**Please note:** I am not looking for comments regarding unneeded optimzation etc.  I am well aware that this, however it is something I have been thinking about recently and wondered if it was possible.

Background info:

If you imagine a users 'cover photo' similar to those seen on Facebook and Google+.  In these apps you can adjust the vertical position of the image by dragging it up or down on your profile page.

This functionality is exactly the same in my app.  User drags the image on their profile page, when they let go of the mouse button an ajax post is sent to server and it updates the database with the new 'top' value.

This 'top' value is read from the database when needed and of course the css is set accordingly.  Everything works fine

Question:

So with all that in mind, is there any way, via PHP of storing meta data to a file itself. In this case a .jpg file.  I know that you can read certain file info data from files but is this directly customizable?  Would it be possible to set a simple meta data property named 'top' and give it an integer, allowing this to be read within the app bypassing the need for the database at entirely?  If so are there any drawbacks to this method?

If of course this is not possible/desirable then fine.  This would also be considered a correct answer, but please explain why.

An unusual question I know.  Hopefully somebody will have an insight on this.

Comment: Yes you can sort images based on their exif information or any file with their meta data

Comment: @Baba +1 is what the OP is looking for. But it is a very roundabout way of doing it.

Comment: If I get you right, you would want to manipulate the exif data of the image, you can do that. For example with http://lsolesen.github.com/pel/

Comment: @ Captain Giraffe ` is there any way, via PHP of storing meta data to a file itself.`  ... I guess that was the main question

Comment: @Baba - Very interesting!  I've just looked at the PHP exif functions.  Could you expand on this at all?  Would it be a performant solution to embed this data and read it back on the fly while generating dynamic html? Or is it a generally bad idea.  Then I will mark the question as answered.

Comment: Why not store it with the rest of the profile information?

Comment: @gordyr ok let me add examples for you now

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Thats exactly what we currently do.  which is fine in 90% of cases.  However there are times (generating hovercards, listing comments) when the only data I need is the userid and currently the coverphoto position.  If I could remove the need to get this coverphoto position then in these instances I will be avoiding a join to our users_meta table in the database.  But as I said I am well aware this would be a micro optimization.  It was more a case of 'wondering if it was possible'

Comment: @gordyr  please note that `exif` is not always available on all images and may be lost during compression of those images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate exif data, which is meta data stored in images. So theoretically you could 'save' the top value in a metadata field... BUT. Don't do it! It's likely gonna be overly expensive for the fact that you just want to save one integer. You can't test it in a standard way, it's not a standard way of doing things so the next guy will miss it if you don't document it well, etc. etc. Your database connection is open anyway, likely you have the user in memory, so writing and reading this value from the user profile is really not a big thing. All in all, not a good idea I think, even though it's original.

Comment: I guess you're correct markus.  Thanks... On the back of your answer i've done some more digging into the exif functions and If I am readying them right, would likely be more expensive than what we are currently doing.  For this reason unless someone comes up with evidence to the contrary, or an even slicker way of doing this in the next few minutes, I will be awarding you the answer. :)

Comment: Just to note though, this is more about retrieving the data for the potentially thousands/millions of other users that may have commented on activities/items when hovering over their avatar (which is retrieved by userid with no DB lookup) and getting the correct top value for their 'mini' coverphoto which is diaplyed on their hovercard, when actually viein their profile it of course is not an issue... for exactly the reasons you mention

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency isn't ultra needed, you can do this with serialize() and unserialize().

```
function save( $file, $data ) {
    file_put_contents( $file, serialize($data) );
}

function load( $file ) {
    return( unserialize( file_get_contents( $file ) ) );
}
```

This will let you store/retrieve variable-length and composition data structures into/from a file.  Limits are you can't dump file pointers and other resource links into the file, and you might run into problems with saving binary information.

Not sure about this, but if you do have binary info, you may need to base64_encode() it first, and decode with base64_decode().

Comment: +1 thanks.  This indeed would do exactly what I want.  However as you correctly stated efficiency would be an issue.  A great approach to the question however and technically a valid answer.  Though on this occasion I won't be with this method, due to the drawbacks previously mentioned. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

While it probably is possible, I believe your best bet would be to persist with a database for this one. Just because it makes more sense, and it's more efficient.

Main point: **a database can be indexed easily**.

Comment: This is true but if he is going to maintain a cache file per user, indexing won't be needed because lookup will be done in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you might be interested in one of these modern NoSQL databases - I have heard that [Redis](http://redis.io/) functions very well for this kind of thing.

Comment: Interesting?  Thanks Jonathan.  Wouldn't modifying the actual 'contents' of the file itself not make the image unreadable (I want to store this data to .jpg files)

Comment: Just seen you're edit so I guess that its not possible in that manner.  Regardless, thank you for the info. :)

Comment: Yeah I initially missed the part that you want to store this metadata in the image itself. If you are willing to store the data separately, then you open up options such as what I described in the edited part, or as pp19dd similarly mentioned.